# Writing a CSV with Tabs

Tags: c#, string, format

I'm trying to build a CSV that has tabs in it. The desired output is:

[image]

As you can see, there are tabs in the third column. This is how my replication comes out:

[image]

The strange thing is, I join the proper amount of tabs onto my string. For example, on the double-nested-looking text, I join two tabs as such:

```
stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format(Pattern, Delimeter, string.Empty, string.Empty, timestamp,
                    string.Join("\t\t", $"SecurityDesc[{fixDict[107][quoteNumber]}] " +
                        $"BidPx[{fixDict[132][quoteNumber]}] BidSize[{fixDict[134][quoteNumber]}] " + 
                        $"OfferPx[{fixDict[133][quoteNumber]}] OfferSize[{fixDict[135][quoteNumber]}]")));
```

For some reason, when viewed in Excel, I cannot see these tabs. Can someone help me figure out why the tabs are not showing?

***Edit:*** This solved it: `$@"{"\\t\\t"}SecurityDesc[{fixDict[107][quoteNumber]}] BidPx[{fixDict[132][quoteNumber]}] "`

StringBuilder is weird. I still didn't get spaced in Excel, but at least the tab character showed up. To get spaced I just did:

`$@"{"    "}SecurityDesc[{fixDict[107][quoteNumber]}] BidPx[{fixDict[132][quoteNumber]}] "`

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?

Comment: @ScottHunter I stated how it looks like in my question. See the second picture.

Comment: You showed what looks like an Excel file (which you likely populated from a CSV file); I was asking about the original CSV.

Comment: Do you have TSV (Tab Separated values) or CSV (Comma Separated Values)?

Comment: @jdweng CSV, but I want some values in the fourth column to have tabs.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm taking the information from a text file that is delimited differently.

Comment: Try changing the column width in excel.  Excel is probably just ignoring the tabs.   Try replacing "\t\t" with "            ".  Or right justify the column instead of left justify.

Comment: @jdweng When I write to a text file, there are also no tabs. Maybe it has to do with string builder?

Comment: Do you want the tabs only at the beginning or between each field?  You do not need the Join if you just want at the beginning.  Just append to string with + "\t\t" +.  If you want tabs between each field then you need an array string.Join("\t\t",new string[] {field1, field2, field3})

Comment: @jdweng That didn't work before. I editted my question and included the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Excel or at least all versions i know, do not support actual CSV and sadly, tabs are not supported by Excel, since you're supposed to layout your data with cells.

Comment: To add on to Patrick's input, although Excel does not reflect the appropriate indentations, and you REALLY need the indentation to be there because you are using this CSV elsewhere subsequently, you can check if the indentation exists by looking at the formula bar. Strangely, indentations are reflected there but not on the cells itself.

Comment: @user12758604 I can't see indentation in the formula bar either. I tried replacing \t with spaces, and still doesn't show.